# Why isn't my react component's css updating dynamically?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, material-ui

I added redux to create-react-app and i've been trying to get a navigator to work. I do this by having the active "page link" highlighted. The code I use for this is a combination of react hooks (using state to remember current page) and the npm package classNames.

classNames(object['key'] && classes.activeItem)

So here I have object['key'] evaluate to true when that particular item is activated so that the item gains the activeItem class.

When I replace object['key'] with true, it works. When I console.log object['key'] after I click it, it also evaluates to true.

Why isn't this working? Thanks!

```
import React, { useEffect, memo } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators, compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { loadPage } from './actions';
import { uploadFile } from '../uploadFile/actions';
import _ from 'lodash';


const styles = theme => ({
  item: {
    paddingTop: 4,
    paddingBottom: 4,
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08)',
    },
  },
  itemPrimary: {
    color: 'inherit',
    fontSize: theme.typography.fontSize,
    '&$textDense': {
      fontSize: theme.typography.fontSize,
    },
  },
  itemActiveItem: {
    color: '#4fc3f7',
  },
  textDense: {}
});

function Navigator(props) {
  const { classes, curPage, onUploadFile, onPageChange, dispatch, ...other } = props;

  let activePage = {
    'invite': false,
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!curPage){
      onPageChange('search');
    }
    activePage = _.mapValues(activePage, () => false);
    activePage[curPage] = true
  });


  return (
    <Drawer variant="permanent" {...other}>
      <List disablePadding>
        <ListItem button className={classNames(classes.logo)}>
          <img src={require("assets/img/logo.png")} alt={''}/>
        </ListItem>

        <ListItem className={classes.categoryHeader} >
          <ListItemText classes={{ primary: classes.categoryHeaderPrimary }}>
            Files
          </ListItemText>
        </ListItem>

        <ListItem
          button
          dense
          className={classNames(classes.item, activePage['invite'] && classes.itemActiveItem)}
          onClick={() => {onPageChange('invite')}}
          >
          <ListItemIcon><PeopleIcon /></ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText classes={{ primary: classes.itemPrimary, textDense: classes.textDense }}>
            Invite To Your Team
          </ListItemText>
        </ListItem>

      </List>

    </Drawer>
  );
}

Navigator.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  onPageChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onUploadFile: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { curPage } = state.app;
  return { curPage };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onPageChange: bindActionCreators(loadPage, dispatch),
    onUploadFile: bindActionCreators(uploadFile, dispatch),
    dispatch
  };
};

const withConnect = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
);


export default compose(withConnect, memo, withStyles(styles))(Navigator);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that function passed to the `useEffect` hook is always run **after the render**.

Your `useEffect` doesn't cause a re-render for component to see the changes. Only change to state causes a re-render. If you want a re-render, you need to use `useState` hook first, and then you need to `setState` from within the `useEffect` hook. Or, you could just run these two lines as part of a render (removing them from the `useEffect` hook, putting them outside):

```
activePage = _.mapValues(activePage, () => false);
activePage[curPage] = true
useEffect(() => {
    if(!curPage){
      onPageChange('search');
    }
});
```

But as I'm looking at your code, I think you could just use `curPage === 'invite' && classes.itemActiveItem` instead of `activePage['invite'] && classes.itemActiveItem` and remove those unnecessary lines related to `activePage` object. It would make things much easier.