# getting 0 when setting DOM element style using current.style.top

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to change the element CSS style `top` property I getting the but when I am setting the style in useEffect hook I am getting `0` on the browser

the value of h and v is based on mouse position.

here is my code below:

```
function App() {
    const h = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const v = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const { x, y } = getValue({divRef});

    useEffect(() => {
        if(h.current){
            h.current.style.top = y as unknown as string;
            console.log(h.current.style.top);
        }

        if(v.current){
            v.current.style.left = x as unknown as string;
            console.log(v.current.style.left);
        }
    }, [x,y])
    
  return (
    <div className='container' ref={divRef}>
       <div id="crosshair-h" className="hair" ref={h}></div>
       <div id="crosshair-v" className="hair" ref={v}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also attached the browser console screenshot:

[browser console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hADSu.jpg)

[Output inside useEffect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBQpX.jpg)

Comment: So i think your problem is   here : const { x, y } = getValue({divRef});     i think you actually get in your useEffect x,y values that equal to 0;  here const { x, y } = getValue({divRef});  you are define your x,y paramters , try to change it , it should work

Comment: No, I am getting the data from it. I checked by printing it on the console. Actually my const { x, y } = getValue({divRef}); is hook and I can't call it inside useEffect hook

Comment: so maybe your hook are change the x,y values to 0; try to console.log it in your use effect

Comment: here is a solution for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56502056/why-isnt-my-react-components-css-updating-dynamically

Comment: I am getting data inside useEffect hook. Check I added a screenshot

Comment: try this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56502056/why-isnt-my-react-components-css-updating-dynamically

Comment: These types of changes should be done in a `useLayoutEffect` hook so they're called during an animation frame. Also, `divRef` is not defined anywhere.